# How to fix click element issue in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to make an instagram bot with selenium, i have to access at instagram, for do that i've wrote this

```
 def login(self):
        self.broswer.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
        WebDriverWait(self.broswer, 10).until(lambda d: d.find_element_by_xpath(PATH_ACCESS_BUTTON).is_displayed())
        username_input = self.broswer.find_element_by_name(NAME_USERNAME_BAR)
        username_input.send_keys(self._username)

        password_input = self.broswer.find_element_by_name(NAME_PASSWORD_BAR)
        password_input.send_keys(self._password)
        WebDriverWait(self.broswer, 5).until(lambda d: d.find_element_by_xpath(PATH_ACCESS_BUTTON).is_displayed())
        WebDriverWait(self.broswer, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, PATH_ACCESS_BUTTON)))

        access_button = self.broswer.find_element_by_xpath(PATH_ACCESS_BUTTON)
        access_button.click()
```

i've ascertained that the `xpath` and the `element names` that i use are correct, in fact the broswer find them,
the problem is that when the code have written the username and the password in the instagram login page, if the broswer window is in the desktop foreground the login button is clicked else if the broswer window is covered by some other application or if it is in another dsktop page the acces button is not clicked.

I've tried too to run this code in headless mode and it works so i don't understand where is the problem

(i launch the broswer in mobile mode adn the code raise no errors)

I'm working with `python3`

OS: `windows`

Broswer: `chrome`

Comment: Just to clarify a little bit, you would like the main login window to come to foreground?

Comment: No, i would like that the login process works too in other desktop pages too or when the browser page is covered from other apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I see that being possible, is with headless. You can't continue using your desktop normally with the application running otherwise. :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using

```
driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to_window
```

to handle the specific Instagram login window.

```
Example:
window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
```

Comment: No, but i don't think that is necessary, i have only one window and when the program has to write username and password in the input boxes they are written. I'll try to do it for see if it works